# Force target to be rebuilt

Tags: bazel

I have the need to, after building targets, trigger a deploy of these.

To really **not waste any time** I would like to have that as a build rule. Now for that to work I would like to have the **deploy be done every time**.
So the question is:

How do I force a target to be rebuilt from scratch deterministically?

Comment: The better way to solve this would probably to be able to call run for multiple targets.

Comment: Or to be able to use remote deployment as input.

Comment: How cardinal is the "deploy once an artifact is built" vs "at the end"?

Comment: The time difference is significant and thus it has to be _once an artifact is built_.

Comment: Ok, fair enough

Answer (score 1):

It would be more bazel-y to do this as a second step, e.g.,

```
java_binary(
    name = "target1",
    ...
)

java_binary(
    name = "target2",
    ...
)

sh_binary(
    name = "deploy-targets",
    srcs = ["deploy-targets.sh"],
    data = [":target1.jar", ":target2.jar", ...],
)
```

Then do `bazel run //path/to:deploy-targets` when you want to deploy.

`deploy-targets.sh` would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for t in $(ls ws/path/to/*.jar); do
  mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=$t ...
done
```

Actions (which are what happen during a build) are not supposed to interact with the outside environment, so deploying kind of breaks that contract.  `run`, on the other hand, can do anything, it's just running a binary.

Using `run` would also solve your "run every time" problem: Bazel can't "cache" forking a binary.

Comment: We have to transfer multiple targets having multiple gigabytes each. And since I cannot `run` multiple targets, doing it serially is a really bad user experience to say the least.

Comment: Can you do `data = [":target1", ":target2", ...]`?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, what you mean by that? All permutations I can think of using `data` would break one of my requirements.

Comment: I edited my answer, does that break any of your requirements?

Comment: Sadly it does as I want to deploy as soon as any target is ready.